# How to data bind to CheckBox using Many to many annotation in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I want to do that;

I have got a work to improve CRUD applications for learning Spring, Hibernate, and JPA. So I want to do Many to Many example but I ask someone to do this.

I want to get employee's driver licenses and update info. I can get employee's info from database to CheckBox in web page using Spring forEach. If employee has which driver license, relational CheckBoxes must be checked. I can update this information.

For example, employee has got driver licenses of "A1" and "M" class. I can get and bind data.

I created tables of "employees", "driving_licenses". 
I created tables of "employee_driving_licenses" for store employee's driver licenses:

employees:

```
id          int
last_name   nvarchar(20)
first_name  nvarchar(10)
```

driving_licenses:

```
id      int 
code    nvarchar(5)
```

employee_driving_licenses:

```
employee_id         int
driving_license_id  int
```

I created table's model class and added JPA annotations. I have got Employee and DrivingLicense  Entity Java class:

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String last_name;
    private String first_name;
    private java.util.Collection<DrivingLicense> driving_licenses = new HashSet<DrivingLicense>();

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter Last Name")
    @Column
    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter First Name")
    @Column
    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employees")
    public java.util.Collection<DrivingLicense> getDriving_licenses() {
        return driving_licenses;
    }

    public void setDriving_licenses(
        java.util.Collection<DrivingLicense> driving_licenses) {this.driving_licenses = driving_licenses;
    }
}
```

DrivingLicense.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driving_licenses")
public class DrivingLicense {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private java.util.Collection<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
                return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof DrivingLicense)) {
                return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((DrivingLicense) obj).getId();
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    @Column
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(name = "employee_driving_licenses", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "driving_license_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public java.util.Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(java.util.Collection<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

I created application DAO, Service, Controller and View classes/pages.

EmployeeController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String employee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
    BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action,
    java.util.Map<String, Object> map) {

    boolean isValid = true;
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    Employee employeeResult = new Employee();
    switch (action.toLowerCase()) {
        case "add":
            if (isValid) 
                employeeService.add(employee);
            employeeResult = employee;
        break;

        case "edit":
            if (isValid) 
               employeeService.edit(employee);
            employeeResult = employee;
        break;
    }
    map.put("drivingLicenseList", drivingLicenseService.findActiveDrivingLicense());
    map.put("employee", employeeResult);
    map.put("activeEmployeeList", employeeService.findActiveEmployees());
    return "employee";
}
```

employee.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="drive_licenses" items="${drivingLicenseList}">
    <form:checkbox path="driving_licenses"
    value="${drive_licenses }" label="${drive_licenses.code }" />
</c:forEach>
```

When I want to update employee's driver licenses, I am receiving an error code as below:

```
{employee=com.ay.model.Employee@573cb29c, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.employee=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult:     1 errors
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'driving_licenses': rejected value      [com.ay.model.DrivingLicense@1,com.ay.model.DrivingLicense@7,com.ay.model.DrivingLicense@8,com.ay.model.Driving    License@9]; codes     [typeMismatch.employee.driving_licenses,typeMismatch.driving_licenses,typeMismatch.java.util.Collection,typeMis    match]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes     [employee.driving_licenses,driving_licenses]; arguments []; default message [driving_licenses]]; default     message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String[]' to required type 'java.util.Collection'     for property 'driving_licenses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of     type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.ay.model.DrivingLicense] for property 'driving_licenses[0]': no     matching editors or conversion strategy found]}
```

How can I get values with type of Collection? Please give advice to me.

And also, If I add this code

```
value="${drive_licenses }"
```

on the web page of employee.jsp, I can see object value  on browser normally. Actually firstly I added this code

```
value="${drive_licenses.id }"
```

But employees's driver licenses were not checked on the CheckBoxes and every CheckBoxes values was got empty. What is the true syntax?

Thank you for supporting.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many parts to this. Roughly:

**One**: create a Wrapper form:

```
public class EmployeeForm{
    private Employee employee;

    //Driving licence needs a 'boolean' selected field
    //Mark as @Transient so not persisted
    //Otherwise create another wrapper/dto which has this boolean field
    //Spring MVC can only bind to indexed fields e.g. List
    private List<DrivingLicence> allAvailableLicences;

    public EmployeeForm(Employee employee, Collecion<DrivingLicence> licenes){
        //set instance vars
    }

    //getters
    //setters
}
```

**Two**: add the following to your controller:

```
//CALLED ON BOTH GET AND POST TO SET UP THE FORM
//FOR EDITING EXISTING EMPLOYEE REPLACE NEW EMPLOYEE WITH THE RELEVANT LOOKUP
@ModelAttribute("employeeForm")
public EmployeeForm getEmployeeForm(@RequestParam("employeeId", required = false) Long employeeId){
    return new EmployeeForm(new Employee(), drivingLicenseService.findActiveDrivingLicense());

}
```

**Three**:

Change your JSP form to bind to the employeeForm: you can used nested properties e.g. employee.name fore the path attributes. For binding licences you need to use the indexed notation as below i.e. set the licence at index x in the list to selected.

```
<c:forEach var="licence" items="${employeeForm.allAvailableLicences}" varStatus="loop">
    <form:checkbox path="licence[${loop.index]}.selected" label="${licence.code }" />
</c:forEach>
```

Four:

Update your form submission handler:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String employee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employeeForm") EmployeeForm employeeForm,
    BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action) {

    //validation etc

    Employee employee = employeeForm.getEmployee();

    for(DrivingLicence licence : employeeForm.getAllAvailableLicences()){
         //our indexed foem check box set the 'selected' field true
         //if selected add to the employee
    }

    //save updated employee

    return "nextPage";
}
```

Comment: I really don't know how to bind between model class and jsp form input data using selected attribute in ' path="licence[${loop.index]}.selected" '. How can I convert data on DAO class?

Comment: Should maybe be  path="employeeForm.allAvailableLicences[{loop.index}].selected" there must be hundreds examples of binding to an indexed field around. Just ensure licence has a transient boolean field 'selected' and pass true as check box value.